# Android Kotlin child onClick blocks parent OnTouch

Tags: android, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener, kotlin

I have this layout hierarchy:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.xxxxxx.Widget
        android:id="@+id/widget1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <com.xxxxxx.Widget
        android:id="@+id/widget2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

I have touch Events for the Parent LinearLayout like this:

```
parent.setOnTouchListener(myCustomTouchParent)

    class MyCustomTouchParent(ctx: Context): View.OnTouchListener {

        private var isScrollingDown = false
        private var isScrollingUp = false
        private val myGestureDetected = GestureDetector(ctx, MyGestureListener())

        var onRecyclerViewMovingDown: (() -> Unit)? = null

        override fun onTouch(p0: View?, e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            myGestureDetected.onTouchEvent(e)

            when(e.action){
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    if (isScrollingDown) {
                        onRecyclerViewMovingDown?.invoke()
                    }
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    Log.i("TAg", "Action Down")
                    isScrollingDown = false
                    isScrollingUp = false

                }
            }
            return true
        }

        inner class MyGestureListener: GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            override fun onScroll(e1: MotionEvent, e2: MotionEvent, distanceX: Float, distanceY: Float): Boolean {
                if(e2.y - e1.y > 0){
                    isScrollingUp = true
                } else if(e2.y - e1.y < 0){
                    isScrollingDown = true
                }
                return super.onScroll(e1, e2, distanceX, distanceY)
            }


        }
    }
```

Basically, this will detect a 'Scroll Up' event on the parent, and will perform some animations. The problem is, as soon as I set a click listener for widget1 and widget2, the touch event of the parent is no longer working. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Unless whatever language you're doing does something weird in its framework, the opposite should be true-  a touch handler not properly written and calling performClick won't call a click handler.  By the way, you may want to tag this question with whatever language/framework you're using, since this isn't java and the Android SDK.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit about "the opposite should be true"

Comment: A touch handler needs to call performClick in order for a click listener to be triggered.  Yours doesn't, so it actually wouldn't ever call the click listener.  The default touch listener does it correctly, but if you override it you need to do it yourself.  Its actually important-  accessibility features depend on the click occurring, so if you don't do it right you'll break screen readers and similar accessibility apps.

Comment: much better, thank you. But the problem isn't that one. The touch listener is defined for the parent and it works fine. The touch listener stops working when i set a click listener to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing that worked for me: In the parent LinearLayout, intercept the touch, call onTouchEvent and return false:

```
override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(ev: MotionEvent): Boolean {
        onTouchEvent(ev)
        return false
    }
```

Move the TouchInterceptor with the Gesture Detector class to the parent onTouchEvent:

```
override fun onTouchEvent(e: MotionEvent): Boolean {
            myGestureDetected.onTouchEvent(e)

            when(e.action){
                MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
                    if (isScrollingDown) {
                        onRecyclerViewMovingDown?.invoke()
                    }
                }

                MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {
                    isScrollingDown = false
                    isScrollingUp = false

                }
            }
            return super.onTouchEvent(e)
        }
```

I don't know if there is a better solution, but this one let me handle touch event on the parent first, then it passed the touch to the childs. There you can set your click listeners.

Also, if you don't set click listeners, the area of touch that contains the clickable item won't trigger touch. so, better set

```
clickable=true
```

in all the items, and then only set listeners when you need.

Answer (score 0):

You have to override both onTouchListeners on your children views and return false, that will make them not override their parent ontouch.

```js
widget1.onTouch { view, motionEvent -> return@onTouch false }
widget2.onTouch { view, motionEvent -> return@onTouch false }
```

Comment: still doesn't work. For some reason, if i set the click listener, parent ACTION_DOWN is called but parent ACTION_UP is not. Basically, i want to  detect a swipeUp in the same region the click listeners are called. Can't have both working, and i'm looking for a workaround. Tried returning false in the children OnInterceptTouchEvent. same result